# Where does STDOUT go with GDB, OopenOCD and semihosting?

Tags: arm, gdb, openocd, semihosting

I am trying to figure out semihostong on ARM (STM32042). I can see `printf` output if I run `openocd` directly from a command line and connect to it from `gdb` over TCP. But if I launch `openocd` from inside `gdb`, the output goes to some big /dev/null in the sky.

If I launch `openocd` myself with

```
$ openocd -f interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg -f target/stm32f0x.cfg
```

and connect to it from `gdb` like so

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:3333
```

I see `printf` output in the `opeocd` terminal. But if I launch `openocd` from within `gdb` as [this link](http://www.openocd.org/doc/html/GDB-and-OpenOCD.html) suggests,

```
(gdb) target remote | openocd -f interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg -f target/stm32f0x.cfg -c "gdb_port pipe"
```

I see all the `openocd` debug messages (e.g., `xPSR: 0xc1000000 pc: 0x08001648 msp: 0x20001800, semihosting`), but not my `printf`s.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you for reminding me. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out slightly more complicated than I wanted. Apparently, it is impossible to launch GDB and OpenOCD in a pipe; they need bidirectional communication over a socket. Because it takes two separate command invocations, and because the configuration for GDB is more than a one-liner, I pulled this into a little repository of its own:

https://github.com/arikrupnik/semihosting-ut

The repo has code that routes stdout to the console, but it does more than that. I've been using it extensively for unit tests on the ARM target for http://www.dish.tc, and have found it very useful. I'm happy to answer questions about it.